# What is the major product of the reaction between 1‐methylcyclohex‐1‐ene and BrCl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halogenation

Would the bromine add to the more substituted carbon due to selectivity?

[image: reaction between 1‐methylcyclohex‐1‐ene and BrCl]

Answer (score 5):

This is not a radical process. $\ce{BrCl}$ is a source of $\ce{Br+},$ so this is the addition of $\ce{Br+}$ to the alkene followed by capture of the cation (bromonium ion) by $\ce{Cl-}$ [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01147a033)].

The product is that of $\ce{Cl-}$ addition to the most stable cation centre i.e. the tertiary centre, so 1-methyl-1-chloro-2-bromocyclohexane is the product.

#### Reference

1. Buckles, R. E.; Long, J. W. The Addition of Bromine Chloride to Carbon—Carbon Double Bonds. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1951**, 73 (3), 998–1000. DOI: [10.1021/ja01147a033](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01147a033).